# Are there any integration frameworks like smooks for .NET?

Tags: c#, xml, integration

I'm doing a lot of work coding merging and data transformation in C#, and I'm just wondering if there are any good "helpers" for doing that instead of handcoding it all.
(that is, without going for a full integration platform like Biztalk)
I'm talking merging and mapping textfiles to produce XML, quite big files but only some very month.

In java, there are a bunch of small ESB's and other things like Smooks that would help, but are there anything like that for C# or is it easier to just go for LINQ?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to perform ETL-like operations in C# code there is always [Rhino ETL](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/01/16/Rhino-ETL-2.0.aspx).

Github repository: https://github.com/ayende/rhino-etl